# Cannot add to cart on frontend react.js, although the end points are working correctly and it is adding items to cart in post man app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

[image][image: Postman response]so I am trying to add to cart. My node.js endpoints are working correctly and I am able to add items to cart when viewed in postman app but it does not display items on the front end, and when inspecting through the chrome developers tools, the items array is empty when on the postman while testing it is successfully storing items.

Here is my server.js

```
    const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let Book = require("./models/bookModel");
const port = 4000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/books", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully..");
});

const bookRoutes = express.Router();
app.use("/books", bookRoutes);
const cartRoutes = express.Router();
app.use("/cart", cartRoutes);

bookRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  Book.find(function(err, books) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json(books);
    }
  });
});

bookRoutes.route("/:id").get(function(req, res) {
  let id = req.params.id;
  Book.findById(id, function(err, book) {
    res.json(book);
  });
});

cartRoutes.route("/").get(function(req, res) {
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  var displayCart = { items: [], total: 0 };
  var total = 0;

  for (var item in cart) {
    displayCart.items.push(cart[item]);
    total += cart[item].qty * cart[item].price;
  }
  displayCart.total = total;

  return res.json(displayCart);
});

cartRoutes.route("/:id").post(function(req, res) {
  req.session.cart = req.session.cart || {};
  var cart = req.session.cart;
  let id = req.params.id;
  Book.findById(id, function(err, book) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if (cart[id]) {
      cart[id].qty++;
    } else {
      cart[id] = {
        item: book._id,
        title: book.title,
        price: book.price,
        qty: 1
      };
    }
    res.redirect("/cart");
  });
});
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: " + port);
});
```

the server response:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "item": "5dd7668f33c21d811b74f403",
            "title": "Modern PHP",
            "price": 25.65,
            "qty": 1
        },
        {
            "item": "5dd6bb36725bbba1ca482eea",
            "title": "Professional Node.js",
            "price": 20.56,
            "qty": 2
        }
    ],
    "total": 66.77
}
```

cart.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import CartItem from "./cart1-item.component.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { throws } from "assert";

export default class Cart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/cart/")
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          items: response.data.items
        });
        console.log(response.data.items);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  checkItems() {
    return this.state.items.map((currItem, i) => {
      return <CartItem book={currItem} key={i}></CartItem>;
    });
  }

  Calculate = item => {
    return item.qty * item.price;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">{this.checkItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

cartitem.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const CartItem = props => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h2>{props.book.title}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CartItem;
```

here is the app.js code for cart route

```
<Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart}></Route>
```

Edited code book-details.component.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../css/styles.css";
import axios from "axios";

export default class BookDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      book: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:4000/books/" + this.props.match.params.id)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ book: response.data });
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
  AddToCart = e => {
    let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id");
    axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/cart/${id}`).then(() => {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/cart/";
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { book, quantity } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col sm-4">
            <img src={`./images/${book.cover}`}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="col sm-8">
            <h2>{book.title}</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Category: {book.category}</li>
              <li>Author: {book.author}</li>
            </ul>
            <p className="button blue">${book.price}</p>
            <p>{book.description}</p>
            <button id={book._id} onClick={this.AddToCart}>
              Add To Cart
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import BooksList from "./components/book-list.component.js";
import BookDetails from "./components/book-details.component.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Navigation from "./components/navigation.component";
import Cart from "./components/cart1.component";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navigation></Navigation>

        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={() => (
            <div className="container">
              <BooksList></BooksList>
            </div>
          )}
        ></Route>
        <Route path="/books/:id" exact component={BookDetails}></Route>
        <Route path="/cart/" exact component={Cart}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Try to console.log(displayCart)

Answer (score 1):

i think i should point out that what you are passing to CartItem is "books" while in the CartItem component you are trying to get "items" from props (`this.props.items`). that part should be `this.props.books.title`.

**UPDATE:**
After you updated your question, i noticed this addition:

> and on clicking the add to cart button it navigates to the link
>
> href={"/cart"} className="button"> Add to Cart

this might be where your problem is coming from. on the API, to add books to cart, you did something like this:

```
cartRoutes.route("/:id").post(function(req, res) {
req.session.cart = req.session.cart || {};
var cart = req.session.cart;
let id = req.params.id;
```

so you are basically making a post request (even though from the code you are not really posting any data since you are just extracting the id from the url parameter. maybe you should consider making this a get request).

the key part here is the post http method and the id that is expected as the url parameter.

to make things simple on yourself, you can change your "add to cart" to something like:

```
<button className="button" id={book.id} onClick={this.addToCart}>
             Add to Cart
         </button>
```

for addToCart, you can do something like this:

```
addToCart=(e)=>{
  let id = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("id");

  axios.post(`http://localhost:4000/cart/${id}`)
    .then(()=>{window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/cart"})
}
```

note that like i said, you can replace the post request above to a get request since you are not actually posting any form data. if you wish to do this, you should also change the corresponding post request in your api to a get request.

Also, note that you can't get cart items posted through postman from the browser. you are using node sessions for cart items storage. you have to create a different react component (if you have not already created it) from where you can send the post request above to your express api

Comment: yes just corrected it but the items array is still empty

Comment: and cartRoutes is basically cartRoutes=('/cart')

Comment: I have edited my question, added the routes like you wanted to see it. Please try helping me out.

Comment: yes it is redirecting successfully now .. but there are still no items being added to cart on clicking add to cart , the items array is empty

Comment: I have edited my question providing you the sufficient details of the changes I made and also added a picture.

Comment: ok yay it worked thank you so much changed post request to get and tadaa!

Comment: hey one question axios.get("http://localhost:4000/cart/${id").then(response => {
      this.setState({ items: response.data.items }); why is the array empty, it is not getting the api response

Comment: hope you are using backticks?

Comment: yeah! I am and the problem still persist the array is empty. I have uploaded a picture of what the browser is showing me.

Comment: i am guessing you are trying to do this in Cart.js right? because your api code is expecting `axios.get("http://localhost:4000/cart")` to return the cart. `axios.get("http://localhost:4000/cart/"+id)` is for storing item in the cart

Comment: how do I get the Id in cart.js

Comment: you only need id when storing items in cart, `axios.get("http://localhost:4000/cart/"+id)`. to return the whole cart, it is not neccessary to have an id. its is a list view. just `axios.get("http://localhost:4000/cart")` should return the whole cart if there is an item in the cart